# setting parent of radwindow when opened from iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, radwindow

Can any of you guide me in solving below problem:

**Scenario:**

I have a webpage which has 4 iframes. In the center iFrame we will be loading the aspx pages. All these is working fine. Now i have a scenario where i need to open a radwindow from Iframe( which is another aspx) page when user clicks a link in that iFrame.

**Problem:**

I am able to open the radwindow but its coming center to the center Iframe which means that half of the content are blocked and it doesnot look graceful also. In this radwindow i am showing a div of that IFrame page it's not a separate URL.

**Solution I tired:**
I have created a method in my main page where i have these 4 IFrames as follows:

```
      function showRadWindow(obj,_title) {
         var oWnd = obj;
         if (this.window.parent != null) {
             oWnd.parent = this.window.parent;
             oWnd._parent = this.window.parent;
         }
         else {
             oWnd.parent = this.window;
             oWnd._parent = this.window.parent;
         }
         oWnd.set_behaviors(Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close);                   
         oWnd.set_title(_title);
         oWnd.set_modal(true);                          
         oWnd.show();
     }
```

I am getting the radwindow from the child IFrame page and calling the function as follows:

```
     function showDialog() {
        var myWnd = $find("<%=myRAD.ClientID %>");
        if (myWnd != null) {
            var oWnd = parent.showRadWindow(myWnd,'New Window');
        }
    }
```

But i am not able to get it center to the main page.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any answer to this question is appreciated